# SetWindowsHookEx() only working for current process

Tags: c++, windows, hook, setwindowshookex

I trying to hook to [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) events of a window created by a separate process, and the only option I know of to accomplish this is to make use of [SetWindowsHookEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx).

I have a C++ executable that is running the following code:

```cpp
HMODULE hDllInstance = LoadLibrary(L"NiceLibrary");
HOOKPROC pOverlayHook = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(hDllInstance, "OverlayHook");
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, pOverlayHook, hDllInstance, 0 /*dwThreadId*/);
```

and "NiceLibrary.dll" contains the function OverlayHook(...). I placed a printf("bla") in the function, to monitor when it is called. For some reason, "bla" is only appearing for events generated by the current process, even though the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) states that:

> dwThreadId [in]
>
> The identifier of the thread with which
> the hook procedure is to be associated. For desktop apps, if this
> parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing
> threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread.

Also, calling [GetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) returns 0 after SetWindowsHookEx(), meaning no error happened.

Do you know what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Does an other `hookId` like `WH_KEYBOARD` or `WH_SYSMSGFILTER` capture something?

Comment: Yes, changing it to `WH_KEYBOARD` captures key presses successfully. I wonder why it won't work with paint events...

Comment: I don't know the answer, but something like WM_PAINT probably has some special case that deliberately excludes it from hooking, due to either security or timing or frequency of being called.   It's probably something that Raymond Chen (http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/) might write a blog about.

Comment: The hook itself is general for any window event. It is in OverlayHook(...) that I check whether the message is WM_PAINT. printf() is called *before* the check, so "bla" should be displayed at any window event.

Comment: are you "NiceLibrary" is loaded to another processes ? i be for test set at begin notepad thread id (instead 0) and check in this single process - are dll loaded and `pOverlayHook` called

Comment: @Neil - i check - WM_PAINT is hooked, and all must work, if no errors in code (of course exist case for 32 vs 64 bit, and security boundaries)

Comment: I tried assigning a thread id manually, but to no avail. Anybody wants the full code?

Comment: WM_PAINT might be hooked, but there might be some special case deep in the guts of Windows that doesn't push that message to hookers.

Comment: Can I ask a different question?  What is it that you are actually trying to achieve?  It might be that you are too fixated with your solution, that there might be a better one that doesn't involve hooking WM_PAINT.

Comment: Note that the hook procedure generally runs *in the context of the hooked process* except where that isn't possible due to a bitness mismatch.  Most GUI processes don't have a console, so the data from your `printf` calls will be ignored.

Comment: @RbMm, did you test the case where the hooking process is x86 and the hooked process is x64?  The hook call should in theory be forwarded to the hooking process in that case, but it seems like a reasonable guess that on-demand messages like `WM_PAINT` don't get forwarded because of the performance impact.

Comment: The DLL, the corresponding executable and the target process are running in 64 bit mode. Bitness is definitely not the issue here.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - now i test with different "bitness" of the application - `WH_GETMESSAGE` not worked at all - i not got any messages, but `WH_KEYBOARD` for example worked. when i test both process x64 - my dll injected and i got `WM_PAINT` as well

Comment: @MathuSumMut - are your DLL is injected in target process ?

Comment: @MathuSumMut - and really how you log function calls ? `I placed a printf("bla") in the function` but if you exactly `printf` using - this will be no worked, as Harry Johnston note

Comment: I placed a breakpoint in the DLL but it was not hit, so printf() is not the issue here. Also, yes I am injecting the DLL in the target process and I have verified that injection is indeed successful.

Comment: So you're running the target process in a debugger?

Comment: No I'm not running the target process in a debugger, only the DLL and the exe that injects it are running in a debugger.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on the instance of a DLL that is running in one process won't affect any other instances of the same DLL that may be running in other processes.

Comment: I managed to make the hook work by making the DLL inject itself into the target process and setting up a hook for itself and then re-inject itself when the hook callback is invoked. It hurts my brain, but it's the only alternative that worked. Thanks for the response anyways. :)

Comment: @MathuSumMut - however all must work without tricks. single call for `SetWindowsHookEx` is enough. if no errors in your code. all what you described - way circumvent instead found,understand and fix. still not understand - are your DLL is loaded in remote process after `SetWindowsHookEx` . and if it loaded - hook will be called. placed breakpoint in your process (which set hook) noting give you. it will be called in remote - and it need debug (most simply use notepad as victim in test)